# Node.JS Global Variable Not Staying Updated

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a global object variable set called `_storage`. It looks like this:

```
_storage = { 
   test : {

   } 
};
```

When a user sends a request to add their info to the "test" object inside of storage, it's supposed to set `_storage.test[1] = true;` for example.

After it sets that, I did this to see what the variable looked like:
`console.log(_storage.test);` and it outputted the correct response:

```
{ '1'  : true }
```

All seems perfect, until the user sends a request to get all the current items in the `test` object. This is where the problem is. The variable seems to empty itself and go back to an empty object `{}`.

The user sends the request to see what's inside of `test` after setting the data in test, so it can't be an issue caused by the user requesting to see the data before even setting it. This is done inside two separate modules, one sets the data and another one gets the data (the two modules aren't just for that only, obviously) but the _storage variable is global and shouldn't be affected by two separate modules.

Here's an example of how it goes down:

1. User sends request to set 1 = true inside of `_storage.test`, making `_storage.test[1] = true;`
2. `_storage.test` is now `{ test : { '1' : true } }` according to console.log
3. User sends request to view all data from `_storage.test`
4. `_storage.test` is `{}` according to console.log, as if it isn't staying set

Here's the code that I use to Get, Set, and Remove the data:

```
exports.GetUserData = function () {

    return global._storage.test;

};

exports.RemoveUserData = function (uid) {

    delete global._storage.test[Number(uid)];

};

exports.AddUserData = function (uid) {

    global._storage.test[Number(uid)] = true;

};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: The example code you provided is not a global variable.  It's at best module scoped (internal to the module).

Comment: @Paul - Shouldn't AddUserData set the data to the module scoped object then if that's the case? Meaning GetUserData would return the module scoped variable that was edited by AddUserData?

Comment: That code has been added since I made my comment.  I'll formulate a full answer when I get to my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think you're not showing all your code, but here's what I did which worked:

```
// index.js
'use strict';

global._storage = global._storage || {};
global._storage.test = global._storage.test || {};

exports.GetUserData = function () {
    return global._storage.test;
};

exports.RemoveUserData = function (uid) {
    delete global._storage.test[Number(uid)];
};

exports.AddUserData = function (uid) {
    global._storage.test[Number(uid)] = true;
};


// other.js
'use strict';

global._storage = global._storage || {};
global._storage.test = global._storage.test || {};

exports.GetUserData = function(){
  return global._storage.test;
}
```

And then I ran this from my repl:

```
> var it = require('./');
undefined
> var other = require('./other');
undefined
> it.AddUserData('1234');
undefined
> it.GetUserData();
{ '1234': true }
> other.GetUserData();
{ '1234': true }
>
```

So that works as designed.  Thing is this... I've been working with node since 2009, and I've *never* felt the need to use global variables.  I doubt your app needs it.  So even though this'll work for you, I recommend you think of another way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! And yeah, I know using global variables is not the way to go. I was trying many different ways and this was my last resort to see if it would work. Anyway, I figured out I was accidentally calling both the AddUserData function and RemoveUserData at the same time, which was obviously the reason it would show as being empty. Thank you for taking the time trying to help me though, I really appreciate it.